# Avoid exiting a for/next on error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I should know better than to not give enough information/good information when asking for help. I have another question which I need to delete/link or merge here... any comment on how to do that would be great.

So the problem is I am trying to write a simple app (yeah, right) to locate a specific file on the local HDD. There WILL be multiple instances of the file (backups etc.) and I want to find each. Issues are that I cannot know how many local hdd there are and I cannot know what directory the file might be in.

So I wanted to

1. iterate through all fixed HDD
2. search the hdd for the file (I always know the name of the file)

I search HDD like this...

```
For Each drive As IO.DriveInfo In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives

If drive.DriveType.ToString = "Fixed" Then
```

So if the found hdd is fixed I do this...

```
 Try

 For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(hdd, "user.config", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

The issue is that I throw an exception, I have the for block above in a try catch, the exception is caught and the code exits.

OK, so I guess this is to be expected. Any suggestions on how to avoid this? Meaning I know I will run across files/directories I do not have permission for, how do I carry on and ignore what I don't care about?

FULL CODE LISTING

```
 Private Sub Command1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Command1.Click
    'variable to hold each hdd name eg: c:\
    Dim hdd As String
    Dim directories As Integer = 0
    Dim files As Integer = 0

    Try

        For Each drive As IO.DriveInfo In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives

            If drive.DriveType.ToString = "Fixed" Then

                'asign the variable hdd a name for this run through
                hdd = drive.Name

                'assign label value for directories
                directories = directories + 1
                Label6.Text = directories.ToString
                Me.Refresh()


                'search the hdd for the file user.config
                Try



                    For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(hdd, "user.config", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        Me.Refresh()

                        '    'assign label value for files
                        files = files + 1
                        Label2.Text = files.ToString

                        Me.Refresh()
                        '    'variable to hold the path for each found file
                        Dim file As String = IO.Path.GetFullPath(filename)

                        '    'update file checking label
                        Label4.Text = file.ToString

                        '    'add each found file to the list
                        List1.Items.Add(file)

                    Next
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try

            End If



        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try
    'iterate through each found drive





End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, this will be a very slow process.

Comment: Why don't you put a try catch code inside your for loop?? so that the exception doesn't make your code to exit

Comment: @Aldipa Well I would love to, but the code never gets past the line I've shown... I watch in the debugger and when it hits that line the code throws the unauthorizedxxx error and it never gets INTO the for...

Comment: please show the whole code block - the way you are doing it is probably not the only way

Comment: In this context do not use GetFiles but EnumerateFiles

Comment: You'll have to search each folder/sub folder individually. ex: Get all the folder in C:\, loop that list and get all the folders undereach, continue, ...

Comment: @PLUTONIX Understood and agreed... code is at the end of the post now

Comment: @the_lotus Afraid of that...

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it out long-wise because you need to handle the IO security issues. And of course a recursive function.

Called by:

```
FindFileOnAllDrivesOfType(System.IO.DriveType.Fixed, "test.txt")
```

Methods:

```
Public Function FindFileOnAllDrivesOfType(ByVal DriveType As System.IO.DriveType, ByVal FileToFind As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim AllLocations As New List(Of String)

    For Each drive As IO.DriveInfo In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives
        If drive.DriveType = DriveType Then
            AllLocations = FindFile(drive.ToString(), FileToFind)
        End If
    Next

    Return AllLocations
End Function

Public Function FindFile(ByVal StartDirectory As String, ByVal FileToFind As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim AllLocations As New List(Of String)

    Try
        For Each dirname As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(StartDirectory)
            AllLocations.AddRange(FindFile(dirname, FileToFind))
        Next

        For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(StartDirectory, FileToFind, IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            AllLocations.Add(filename)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        'Do nothing as we can't get a directory listing
    End Try

    Return AllLocations
End Function
```

Comment: Well, this seems to be progress, thanks. But I have the file in a couple of known locations and it is not being returned. As someone mentioned it is a lengthy process so it's not something I can just step through (tens of thousands of files to search). I think at this point I'm going to have to keep searching for an answer. One of the issues I see with certainty is that there are restricted files or directories all over the place in windows and if any of these throws an exception the process is halted (the for stops) I have an app that maps out every file so I know it can be done

Comment: @jsteffler This is strictly a permissions issue. Try what I posted, build an EXE, and run it as Administrator.

Comment: Thanks... trying that. I do understand it is a permissions issue, just seeing that any error kills the loop. I just want to bypass those files or directories. Hopefully this will do that.

Comment: Well I have made progress, thanks so much. BUt I am still not able to get this to work, it still passes over such things as my own documents folder no matter how I run it. But at least it doesn't stop. I will update when I get it sorted.